# how to get a value from a form blade index to jquery from blade edit?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

i want to edit from one annonces, then the form of balde edit changes according to souscotegory_id, me i want to know souscategory_id comes from blade index to jquery from blade edit, in my case it gives me null.

**index.blade.php**

```
<a href="{{ url('annonces/'.$annonce->id.'/edit') }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></a>
```

**AnnonceController.php**

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        $annonce = Annonce::find($id);
        return view('annonces.edit')->with([
            'annonce'         => $annonce
        ]);
    }
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
let souscategory_id = window.sessionStorage.getItem('souscategory_id');
        alert(souscategory_id);
```

Comment: You want to edit from one annonces?  category_id is NULL?  Is that a JavaScript variable that is NULL?

Comment: @FSDford thx for u answer ,imean souscategory_id